# JavaScript: сохранить переменную в *.txt

Tags: php, javascript, html

Пытаюсь реализовать взаимодействие с пользователем. 
Есть две кнопки:

```
<table width='20%'cellspacing=2 cellpadding=0>
        <tr><td><abbr title="Сохранить настройки текущего проекта."><input type="submit" name='save' value="Сохранить"></abbr></td>
        <td><abbr title="Сохранить новый проект с настройками текущего."><input input type="button" value="Сохранить как" onClick="open_dialog()"></abbr></td></tr>
</table>
```

Если выбираем "Сохранить как", то открывается диалог, который реализован следующий образом:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_dialog() {
  var new_name=prompt("Введите имя проекта", " ");
   alert("Создан новый проект "+new_name);
}
</script>
```

Мне нужно забрать переменную new_name и сохранить её в текстовый файл на сервере. 
Если JavaScript это не умеет, то как передать данные из JavaScript в PHP?

Comment: Я тут написал ответ и удалил, потому что он был для сохранения файла к себе на компьютер. Чтобы сохранить на сервер, надо отправить на него запрос (например с помощью $.ajax) с нужными данными, и на сервере его уже обработать.

Comment: @Утка а если попробовать через объект FormData, получится?

Comment: да но это не ie-friendly

Answer (score 1):

> Если JavaScript это не умеет, то как передать данные из JavaScript в PHP?

[Ajax jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)